# How Can I Convert PDF to JPEG in Java?

Tags: java, pdf, jpeg, pdfbox

I have been trying to convert PDFs to images in Java -  I tried PDFBox but it actually converts with a pretty bad resolution.

Is there any other method that I can use to convert PDFs to images with fine quality?

If there is an option to do that with PDFBox, could you give me some sample code as well?

I have been trying this more than 1 week now...

Thanks.

Comment: I work for the company that makes PDFOne. Last year, we published an article titled [Convert PDF To High-Resolution Images Using Java](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=135&t=Convert_PDF_To_High-Resolution_Images_Using_Java). The example in this article uses the commercial Version 3 of PDFOne. I don't think that the methods for exporting PDF pages to images is available in the Google Code version.

Answer (score 2):

Try one of:

- [jPedal](http://www.jpedal.org/)
- [PDFOne](http://code.google.com/p/pdfonejava/)

Both are PDFBox alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for the information but I am trying to use PDFOne which is not commercial version (Google Project Hosting) I cannot find any information how I can convert PDF to images. is there any direction how I can use this library?? or can u give me a simple code to convert PDF to image... thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the JPedal examples takes advantage of any high resolution images in the PDF to upsample the output for best quality (http://www.jpedal.org/support_egHiRes.php).